# Collapse Google Vis Table When Row Content Hidden

Tags: jquery, css, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have a spreadsheet where I am storing about 5000 rows across 25 columns. There are specific category header rows and then subcategory rows. I have formatted the cells as HTML with class names so that I can conditionally format them and the user can modify them using jquery in my web app.

Here is an example of the spreadsheet:

[image]

I am using HTML Service and a Google Visualization ChartWrapper Table in Google Apps Script to display this data to the user. I am using the following jQuery code to unhide the hidden rows:

```
   function toggleByClass(className) {
     $("."+className).toggle();
   }
```

My issue is that the rows with hidden divs still have a height, where I am looking to have them fully collapse. furthermore, even rows where I delete the content there is row created in the visualization

I was able to hide the row/cell borders using the CSS Property `empty-cells:hide;` but the row height remains.

My question: How would I go about hiding rows while the content is hidden but showing them when they are unhidden?

[image: Toggle Rows Gif]

Comment: `display: none`? It's unclear what code you use to hide the content.

Comment: I am creating the elements that are inside the table cells in the google sheets before passing them to the web app. In `google.visualization.ChartWrapper` I set options to `allowHtml: true`. The screenshot above, if you look at cell A3 you can see an example of what the hidden div looks like in the first subcategory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to toggle the table row, instead of the contents,
try it like this...

```
$('.' + className).closest('tr').toggle();
```

hide initially by using toggle when the table's `'ready'` event fires

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
  toggleByClass('oddNumber');
  toggleByClass('evenNumber');
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'B');
  data.addRows([
    ['<div class="header">header 1</div>',  10000],
    ['<div class="oddNumber">subcategory 1</div>',  10000],
    ['<div class="oddNumber">subcategory 1</div>',  10000],
    ['<div class="oddNumber">subcategory 1</div>',  10000],
    ['<div class="header">header 2</div>',  10000],
    ['<div class="evenNumber">subcategory 2</div>',  10000],
    ['<div class="evenNumber">subcategory 2</div>',  10000],
    ['<div class="evenNumber">subcategory 2</div>',  10000],
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table($('#chart_div').get(0));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    toggleByClass('oddNumber');
    toggleByClass('evenNumber');
  });

  table.draw(data, {
    allowHtml: true
  });

  function toggleByClass(className) {
    $('.' + className).closest('tr').toggle();
  }

  $('.toggle-button').on('click', function () {
    toggleByClass(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<button class="toggle-button ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="oddNumber">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev"></span><span>&nbsp;Toggle Odd</span>
</button>

<button class="toggle-button ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="evenNumber">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next"></span><span>&nbsp;Toggle Even</span>
</button>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was able to get the subcategory rows to toggle out of visibility, which is a huge help. How would I assure that by default all of the subcategory rows are hidden? Originally in the spreadsheet cells, I was setting `display:none;`, but need a way to do this as I'm drawing the table to only subcategory rows.